# code base for GIT master/feature branch

Tags: git

This is probably one of the silliest questions i have asked. I'm trying to use Git for a project set up by someone else. I have pulled the "master" branch from the remote repository and I branched it to a "my branch".

The question is that I still see only one code base. Do I use Git Bash to switch to my user branch and work on the same code base? I am just not getting this concept as I'm used to seeing different code bases for different branches.

Is it that I use Git command window to switch the branch, keep working on the code base that I got when I cloned the repository and then when I'm done, i merge it back to my "local" master before pushing to remote?

Did I get this right? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are describing/asking.  Can you explain more about how you have things setup and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to work on the project that is set up by someone else. They want me to create a local branch, work on it and merge it back to their master. I'm new to Git and I managed to pull down the code (clone command) and I created a branch using git checkout -b mybranch. but I don't see any codebase for the branch. where is it?

Comment: Alex J, you're on the new branch! By default when you create a new branch, it copies over what's in the master branch to your new branch. Try adding two or three files, and then checking out the master branch... you'll see that the files are gone. But if you checkout your branch again, the files will reappear.

Comment: ok, i didn't know that the same physical folder contents just keep switching when different branches are chosen. Phewww!

Comment: I definitely recommend making a test repository and playing around a bit, it'll help you get a sense of what's going on. Also, you might find it useful to [add the name of your git branch to your bash prompt](http://hocuspokus.net/2009/07/add-git-and-svn-branch-to-bash-prompt/). If it's too advanced don't worry about it, but I find it to be a very helpful reminder of what branch I'm on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(in all the below examples, *foo* is the name of a branch)

You only see the code for the branch you're currently on. To see a list of branches, type,

```
git branch
```

To switch to a different branch, type:

```
git checkout foo
```

To delete a branch, type:

```
git branch -D foo
```

To merge two branches, change to one of them, then type:

```
git merge foo
```

The idea is that you only see the code that is currently relevant (the branch you are working on). I find [Github.com's tutorial on Git](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/) to be pretty clear. Another good resource is the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/).

One important note: when you pull from a remote repository, you will be default only pull the Master branch. If you want to pull other branches, you'll have to specify them directly.

Answer (score 2):

Git branching is pretty confusing for beginners.

You only see one code base right now because your two branches are exactly the same.

Use 'git checkout ' to switch to the other branch.  Now the source code in your filesystem will change to that other branch.  If you haven't made any changes, then it'll look the same.

If you're confused as to which branch you're actually on, run 'git branch' with no parameters, and it will display all branches, with your current branch with an asterisk.

Here's more info.
http://gitref.org/branching/

Comment: ok, so it is the same code base that keeps changing based on what branch i'm on.