# Git branch switching does not change code folder files

Tags: git

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406651/code-base-for-git-master-feature-branch) question.

I cloned the remote master project folder using `git clone git@git.mytest.com:TEST` command. from the Git root, I did a `cd Test` command to move into that folder. I then created a branch using `git checkout -b myBranch`. Now on the git bash it shows that i'm in the new branch. I created a test.txt file in the Test folder and then switched my branch to master. I still see the text file. Isn't Git supposed to not show the test.txt since it not part of master. Do I need to commit my changes in the branch if this has to happen.

I thought initially this may have happened because it is not part of my .net project (that I have in the master and branch). But the same happened when I tried to add a file to mybranch. When I switch my master, I still see the changed icon for the folders in the fie system.

What am I missing? Thank you for all your help as I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out Git now. Every time I think I have got it, there is always something.

Comment: Haha +1 for `Every time I think I have got it, there is always something.` That's GIT for you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No it's not part of your `master` branch, but it's not part of `myBranch` either. It is *untracked*, because you never committed the file. Running `git status` you'll see it listed as untracked. Since it was never staged or committed, Git doesn't (and can't) manage its existence, so it stays there regardless.

Further, modified files remain between branches if they can. Else Git will give you an error when switching branches about a dirty working tree. This is, again, because Git has no internal copy of those changes, they exist only in your filesystem, and not within Git till they are committed.

Comment: +1 Git does know about files as soon as you `git add` them (it puts them in its *index*), but they aren't part of a *branch* until they've been put in a `commit`

Comment: I've commited it already, and when change to a branch that NOT have that changes, surprise, folders are still there.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Perhaps your `.gitignore` is different between the two branches.

Comment: The problem is with already-ignored folders, when change branch, ignored folders are still there, show (atleast) dissapear if not "deleted"