# Git checkout doesnt revert files

Tags: git, git-checkout

Using git on mac (sierra); git version 2.8.4 (Apple Git-73)

```
git checkout <master>
```

command doesn't revert the file changes which are made on another branch.

Here's what i did.

```
cd project_folder
git clone -o origin -b master git@gitlab.corp.xyz.com:prj/PRODUCTION.git
git branch -b new_branch
git checkout new_branch
<make changes to an existing file>
git checkout master
```

Am expecting to see a clean version of master without the changes that were made in new_branch. But the changes that i made is carried forward when i switch between branches.

Previously (long time back) this used to work like what i expected. Am i missing something?

I did fair amount of google & stackoverflow searches. Didn't yield a result i was looking for. Closest results that i got are, but they didn't help me much.
1. https://superuser.com/questions/892847/git-branch-branches-not-different
2. [Git branch switching does not change code folder files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527097/git-branch-switching-does-not-change-code-folder-files)

Comment: As Tim Biegeleisen points out this is the expected behaviour. You can always use stash your changes before checking out master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, and is what I normally see when using Git.  From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) for git checkout:

> To prepare for working on <branch>, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch. **Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept**, so that they can be committed to the <branch>.

If you need to switch branches and your working directory is not clean, here are a couple of options:

1) you can make a temporary commit on your current branch:

```
git commit -m 'WIP'
```

I say "temporary" but really this is just like any other commit.  The only difference is that when you return to this branch you will *amend* this commit once you have finished the task via:

```
git commit --amend -m 'Finished WIP'
```

2) Stash away your changes via

```
git stash
```

Stashing will create *two* commits, one for the working directory and one for the stage.  When you want to bring these changes back you can *apply* these changes via:

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I see that if i commit my changes and then switch to master, then i dont get changes from new_branch. Is there any way to do this without doing a commit. Basically am working on new_branch and then suddenly a hot_fix came up which needs to be done on master. How do i accomplish this?

Comment: @CyriacGeorge I updated my answer.  You can either make a temporary commit or stash away your changes.  Stash is probably the easier option.

Comment: thanks once again. i have accepted this answer, as it answers the original question. is there a command to undo the commit; meaning, remove the entry from new_branch's history but at the same time keep the modifications in the file, for further changes.

Comment: The idea behind a temporary commit is that you _amend_ the commit after returning later to the branch.  Hence, all your important changes are still safe there, and you can do whatever else you want.  If you _don't_ want the changes, then you never should have committed them in the first place.

Comment: I'll note that if you want to make a temporary commit, then back it out while preserving in-progress modifications, you can use `git reset`, with either `--soft` or the default `--mixed` actions.